# Killing tensor in the Kerr metric

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, symmetry, vector-fields, kerr-metric

It was famously shown by [Carter](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1968PhRv..174.1559C) that the Kerr metric possesses a 4th non-obvious constant of the motion, derived from the separability of the Hamiltonian. This constant is related to a Killing tensor.

**My question is**, is it possible to show apriori the existence and value of this Killing tensor from the Kerr metric, before considering the separability of the Hamiltonian?

Answer (score 8):

The [Killing tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_tensor) is defined as a symmetric tensor $K_{\alpha \beta}$ whose total symmetrization of the covariant gradient vanishes
$$K_{(\alpha \beta;\gamma)} = K_{\alpha \beta;\gamma} + K_{ \beta\gamma;\alpha}+ K_{\gamma \alpha;\beta}= 0$$
This can be seen as a higher-order generalization of the Killing vector $\xi_\mu$ and the Killing equation which says that the symmetrization of its covariant gradient vanishes
$$\xi_{(\mu;\nu)} = \frac{1}{2}(\xi_{\mu;\nu} + \xi_{\nu;\mu})=0$$
In special coordinates where $\xi_\mu$ is tangent to the lines of some coordinate $X$, we can show that the Killing equation is equivalent to the requirement that the metric is independent of $X$.

The equations fulfilled by a Killing vector or a Killing tensor are "just" homogeneous linear partial differential equations with non-constant coefficients. I.e., we can solve them directly by brute force. Consider Minkowski space-time in Cartesian coordinates. There we have the covariant gradient equal simply to the coordinate gradient and a trivial example fulfilling the Killing equation is a constant vector $\xi_\mu$. Similarly, a trivial example of a Killing tensor in Minkowski is any constant symmetric tensor $K_{\mu \nu}$. I.e., we do not need to generally consider the separability of the Hamilton-Jacobi equation to obtain the Killing tensor.

---

On the other hand, in the case of a generally curved space-time (including Kerr), it is virtually impossible to find analytical solutions to the Killing-tensor equation by brute force. You have to use special algebraic techniques such as the spinor techniques used by [Walker and Penrose in 1970](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01649445) to derive (or guess) the Killing tensor without reference to the separability of equations of motion. In the light of these procedures, it does not seem as such a stretch to use the Hamilton-Jacobi equation to indirectly look for a Killing tensor.

Nevertheless, looking just at the separability of the Hamilton-Jacobi equation of a geodesic is not a surefire way to see whether the space-time has a Killing tensor or not. It has been shown that the Hamilton-Jacobi equation separates if and only if you are in a special set of adapted coordinates (Boyer-Lindquist and similar in Kerr, I like the way this is reviewed by [Chervonyii and Lunin](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.06154.pdf)). If you are in a generic set of coordinates, your Hamilton-Jacobi equation does not separate even though you have a Killing tensor.

Furthermore, another important object often called the ``square root" of the Killing tensor, the [Killing-*Yano*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_tensor#Killing-Yano_tensor) tensor, cannot be found by the Hamilton-Jacobi method. The Killing-Yano tensor of rank two is an antisymmetric tensor $Y_{\alpha \beta}$ whose covariant gradient is also antisymmetric
$$Y_{\alpha (\beta;\gamma)} = 0$$
You can then show that $K_{\alpha \beta} = Y_{\alpha \gamma} Y^\gamma_{\;\; \beta}$ is a Killing tensor. The existence of the Killing-Yano tensor implies separability of the Dirac equation on the curved background. This means that in principle you can circumvent the Hamilton-Jacobi equation by instead looking for the Killing-Yano tensor from the separability of the Dirac equation, and squaring it to obtain the Killing tensor. However, the construction of [the Dirac equation on curved background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation_in_curved_spacetime) is not trivial.

Thus, it still seems to me that looking for the separation constant of the Hamilton-Jacobi equation for a geodesic is the easiest trick in trying to find the Killing tensor.

---

If you are looking more for a pragmatic way to simply read of the Killing tensor from the Kerr metric and any metric with a Killing tensor, the recipe goes as follows.

You have to be in coordinates $\xi, \eta$ (plus the ones corresponding to Killing-vector directions) where the inverse metric components acquire the form
$$g^{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{f_\xi(\xi) - f_\eta(\eta)} (X^{\mu \nu}(\xi) + Y^{\mu\nu}(\eta))\,,$$
where $X^{\eta \nu} = Y^{\xi \nu}=0$. You can see that the Kerr metric in Boyer-Lindquist coordinates $r,\vartheta$ has exactly this property.

Your Killing tensor then is
$$K^{\mu\nu} = -\frac{f_\xi Y^{\mu \nu} + f_\eta X^{\mu \nu}}{f_\xi - f_\eta}$$
This can be verified by brute-force calculation.

However, the *derivation* of this formula would be once again easiest by considering the Hamilton-Jacobi equation because these $\xi$ and $\eta$ are once again coordinates in which the HJ equation separates.